# Loading a local geojson file in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to load a locally-saved geojson file in Mapbox GL JS, however it does not show up when loaded in the browser.  It works when I swap out a live URL for the 'data', however when I reference the local file, it does not work.  I have checked that the local file is indeed valid and actually there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add a polygon to a map using a GeoJSON source</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.13.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.13.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWRhbWJydWVja25lciIsImEiOiJjbGVoNTYwaTUwcm8zM3htejV0MHpxY2RiIn0.XMLudwO9aIRQquhkKGEnVg';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v11',
            zoom: 10,
            center: [-73.98, 40.76],
            //projection: 'globe'
        });

        map.on('load', () => {

            var dataGJ = 'data/borough-boundaries.geojson';

            // add a source layer for the borough boundaries
            map.addSource('borough-boundaries', {
                type: 'geojson',
                data: dataGJ
                //data: 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/geospatial/tqmj-j8zm?method=export&format=GeoJSON'
            })

            map.addLayer({
                'id': 'borough-boundaries-fill',
                'type': 'fill',
                'source': 'borough-boundaries',
                'paint': {
                    'fill-color': 'green',
                }
            })
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>`
```

I tried saving the file locally and referencing it in the code, but still it does not actually load up in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mapbox GL styles, data URLs need to be absolute: `http://localhost/data/borough-boundaries.geojson` or similar.

Comment: Thank you!  So if there is a file lets say in the C:\Data\ directory - what would be the correct way to call that?

Comment: You would need a way to access it via HTTP.

Comment: Thanks - my mistake was I was opening up the base html file locally, vs from the local server.  That fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If @Steve's solution did not work, try referencing [this example](https://github.com/friendlycities-gatech/chainness/blob/main/index.html) I wrote in the past. It renders data from a local path (relative path to the data from index.html). I did not use map.addSource() and I just specified the source in map.addLayer() like below.

```
map.on('load', () => {
        map.addLayer({
          id: 'restaurant',
          type: 'circle',
          source: {
            type: 'geojson',
            data: 'data/chainness_point_2021.geojson' 
          }
        });
```